# Definitions for 挒 and 掤

Tags: characters

Saw these two characters in a Tai Ji DVD: 掤 and 挒, but I couldn't find them in my dictionaries.  Are these archaic, very specialized, or something else?
The English the definitions the Tai Ji teacher provided are:
掤 - expanding energy,
挒 - splitting energy.

This is the full list of "energies" that were discussed in the lesson. The definitions in the lecture seemed (to me) to be similar to the dictionary definition, except for the above two.
掤 - expanding
履 - roll back / redirect
擠 - squeezing
按 - pushing
採 - pulling (down)
挒 - splitting
肘 - elbow
靠 - body leaning

Let me know if 掤 and 挒 are very specialized words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**挒** is defined in *Grand Ricci* as:

> liè
>   3 (Arts mart.) Se fendre; utiliser les deux forces opposées pour bloquer ou déséquilibrer l’adversaire.

Which [Google translates](https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl=auto&tl=en&text=3%20(Arts%20mart.)%20Se%20fendre%3B%20utiliser%20les%20deux%20forces%20oppos%C3%A9es%20pour%20bloquer%20ou%20d%C3%A9s%C3%A9quilibrer%20l%E2%80%99adversaire.) as:

> 3 (Arts mart.) Split; use the two opposing forces to block or unbalance the opponent.

Arts mart. should probably just be switched to martial arts.

---

**掤** is defined in *Grand Ricci* as:

> bīng
>   2 (Arts mart.) Mouvement des bras pr repousser l’adversaire ds la direction d’où il vient.

Which [Google translates](https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl=auto&tl=en&text=2%20(Arts%20mart.)%20Mouvement%20des%20bras%20pr%20repousser%20l%E2%80%99adversaire%20ds%20la%20direction%20d%E2%80%99o%C3%B9%20il%20vient.) as:

> 2 (Arts mart.) Movement of the arms to repel the opponent in the direction from which he has come.

Comment: Thanks!  does the Grand Ricci provide accepted tones for modern pronunciation?

Comment: @user6546 yup, I’ve added them into my answer above.